# Standard notation for the indicator function of the odd integers

Tags: soft-question, notation

Is there a commonly used notation for the indicator function of the odd integers? One candidate I think is $$1_{2\mathbb{Z}+1}(x),$$ and I could always define one, $$\chi(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 &\text{if }x\text{ is odd} \\0 &\text{otherwise} \end{array}\right..$$ Just wanted to ask the community as I can't find much online.

Comment: I tend to use this as well, with the minor difference that $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of $A$ for me (instead of $1_A$).

Comment: Analysts often use $\chi$ and probabilists often use $\mathbf 1$ hence you might want to use $\chi_{2\mathbb Z+1}$ or $\mathbf 1_{2\mathbb Z+1}$

Comment: I think I'll use $\chi_{2\mathbb{Z}+1}(x)$ then. Thanks.